# Global filter all for React-Table v7

Tags: reactjs, filtering, react-table

I'm trying to figure out how to do global filter all (instead of per column) for React Table v7.

The [example that they have](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering) shows only per column filters.

I've [tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-react-table-v7-with-global-filtering-mrh29) to create a global version but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Tanner has updated the react-table API to contain a `useGlobalFilter` hook. The documentation for this can be located [here](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter).